# Laravel 10 using controller to store data to MySQL database

Tags: php

I am trying to test a controller function that would store specific data to the mySQL database , that is given specific input this input will be stored to the data base using an API & will be done through Postman .

for some reason I am getting an internal 500 server error when testing this request oute in Postman. I am fairly new to using laravel & MySQL data base . If I can get any advise on what i have to fix as I am having issues on this request being done successfully. Below I will show my controller, migration , route  & model files . I am on a MAC using tableplus & docker for the MySql database.

Controller :

```html
use App\Models\BookRating;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookRatingController extends Controller
{
    
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function CreateRating( Request $request)
    {
       // create a function that inserts data to data base ( create a book rating)
       $bookrating = new BookRating; 
       $bookrating->Rating=$request->Rating;
       $bookrating->userId=$request->userId;
       $bookrating->bookId=$request->bookId;
       $bookRating= $bookRating->save();
       return ["Data has been saved"];
       }
```

Model:

```html
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookRating extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'Rating',
        'userId',
        'bookId'
    ];
}
```

Migration :

```html
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('bookRating', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Rating');
            $table->string('userId');
            $table->string('bookId');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Route :

```html
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BookRatingController;
use App\Http\Models\BookRating;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post("CreateRating",[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateRating']);//adding a bookrating to database API -- POST METHOD--
```

Here is the request I am submitting through postman (where i input the values) but am getting a error 500 :

[image]

Comment: you have answer in Postman. Undefined variable $bookRating..
so its typo

Comment: Your initialized variable is `$bookrating` not `$bookRating` (small "r") . Check the saving part

Comment: I updated that error now I am getting the following error message in postman "<!--
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for http failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `book_ratings` where `book_ratings`.`id` is null limit 1) in file /Users/splashysplash/Documents/GitHub/group7-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 829"

Comment: did you set up your `.env` correctly? what do you have on your DB_ variables?

Comment: @9uifranco I am not going to lie , my ENV files did have issues initally,  my buddy just had me copy & pase their env file to my project. I included entire code of my env file below . 

my table/MySQL data base name is group7_project btw

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```php
$bookRating= $bookRating->save();
```

to this:

```
$bookrating->save();
```

Comment: there is no variable named `$bookRating` when `save` is being called

Comment: You're correct. Now it's fixed. Tried to fix a typo with a typo, my bad

Comment: Typo type problems should be closed and not answered as others can't use them.